# Un div al lado de otro, ambos pegados abajo

Tags: html, css

Estoy editando una plantilla de WordPress y lo que me falta es poner dos `div`, **uno al lado del otro**, así ("2" y "3"):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya traté con `float:left;` en el div "2" y `overflow:hidden;` en el div "3" y el resultado se acerca a lo que busco. Pero necesito que ambos se queden pegados abajo dentro del div "1" como se ve en la imagen, y **el problema al aplicar esas propiedades CSS es que el div "2" se queda pegado arriba a la altura del div "3"**.

Comment: Alex, te sugiero agregar el código que hayas y, por favor lee [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: Hola. Creo que no es necesario poner el código porque lo descrito en mi pregunta es todo, no hay más.

Comment: Alex, para facilitar mejores respuestas, es bueno que sigas las sugerencias de los administradores de añadir el código de los intentos que hayas hecho.

Comment: Yo, realmente, no entiendo por qué me piden más código... El que menciono en mi post es todo (son solo tres div, "1" con "width:600px" y "2" con "width:90px;") , además al final advierto que intenté aplicando dos propiedades CSS a los div "2" y "3" y que eso dio un resultado que no es el que busco.

Comment: @Alex aunque te parezca irrelevante el código ayuda mucho. Evita que quien responda tenga que crearlo de cero, se pueden ver otros errores o problemas que tú no hayas detectado, en el caso de HTML y CSS *Stack overflow* tiene además un snnipet que permite ejecutarlo. El código muchas veces se explica por si mismo y eso ayuda a encontrar una respuesta o a entender mejor el problema.

Comment: @blonfu 1: Nunca dije que me parezca irrelevante. 2: El código necesario está en mi pregunta, la que es bastante general debido a que yo solo encontraba soluciones a casos muy específicos, lo que no me servía y supongo le habrá pasado a muchos. 3: No voy a seguir respondiendo a comentarios ya que el punto de mi pregunta fue resuelto por alguien que entendió a lo que me refería (todo se solucionaba aplicando dos propiedades CSS al div "1", era así de fácil).

Comment: Yo solo quería explicar porque te piden código. En este sitio no se trata solo de ayudar en un problema concreto sino, siempre que sea posible, ayudar a la comunidad creando un repositorio de preguntas/respuestas que pueda consultar todo el mundo. Creo que te lo has tomado como algo personal y no es así, al menos por mi parte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Espero que te sirva cualquier duda no dudes en consultarme.

```css
.box01{
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.box02{
  width: 90px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.box03{
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box01">
  <div class="box02"></div>
  <div class="box03"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Esto es lo que buscaba, muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Quedó perfecto, mejor imposible :)

Comment: de nada, estamos para ayudarnos entre todos, procura nunca usar selectores tipo id dentro de css eso es una mala practica, buena suerte con tu proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

si solo lo que buscas es hacer que dos div se pongan en la parte de abajo de un div haz lo siguinte:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background: black; width:600px; height: 100px;">
 <div style="background: red; width:90px; height: 50px; display: inline-block; margin-top: 50px;"></div>
 <div style="background: blue; width:90px; height: 50px; display:inline-block; margin-top: 50px; "></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

creo que el codigo no necesita mucha explicacion ya que es algo facil.

Si quieres que ellos se adapten te sugiero que uses porcentajes en lugar de pixeles.

Answer (score 0):

Complementa el float con position:relative;

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
        <style>
            #div1{
                background-color: black;
                width: 40%;
                color: white;
            }
            #div2{
                background-color: red;
                width: 40%;
                float: left;
                position: relative;     
            }
            #div3{
                background-color: green;
                width: 40%;
                float: right;
                position: relative;

            }

            </style>
        </head>

        <body>
        <div id="div1">Este es el div 1</div>
        <div id="div2">Este es el div 2</div>
        <div id="div3">Este es el div 3</div>
    </body>
</html>
```